Show that fourier coefficient map is injective
Suppose that we take a function $f \in L^1(S^1)$, where $S^1$ is the unit circle, and we define the $n$-th Fourier coefficient as $$\hat{f}(n) = \langle f, z^n \rangle _{L^2(S^1)}$$
where the $L^2$ inner product is taken on the unit circle. Noting that $\{z^n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(S^1)$, how could you prove that the map $f \to \hat{f}$ is an injective map?
In terms of my attempts: since it is linear, I have reduced the problem to showing that if $\hat{f} = 0$ then $f = 0$. If $\hat{f} = 0$ then this means that $f$ is orthogonal to each of the basis elements of $L^2(S^1)$, and so it is orthogonal to every element of $L^2(S^1)$.
This is where I am stuck; I am not sure what to do from here. Is there a property of $L^p$ spaces that I am missing? How could I use these facts to conclude that $f = 0$? Thank you

You have to consider $\hat f (n)$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$, not just $n \in \mathbb N$. If it is just $\mathbb N$ then your map is not injective.

You will have to consider carefully what is meant by a basis in this context (it involves some topological notions, like denseness and completeness, and you'll have to be careful what exactly you consider to be the elements of $L^2$)

Linear combinations of ${z^{n}:n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,...}$ are dense in $C(S^{1})$.
